# How secure is the openSSH login?

Tags: networking, ssh, security, raspberry-pi, openssh

I am using several RPi's on my router, which have port forwarding for the port 22 out into the evil internet. When I connect to the RPi using openSSH (Powershell: ssh username@ip-adress -p 12345) it prompts a password for the raspberry user.

The password contains small and capital letters, numers and symbols and has 15+ characters.

#### Question:

How secure is that method of logging in and if it is poor, how can I secure it in the right way?

The RPi has full access to all the network devices in my home, including drives with sensitive data. That's why it is really important to be safe.

Comment: It’s as secure as the password or the key size of your certificate (for key authentication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That is moderately secure, but you can do much better.** The limits of your current solution include requiring vigilance to protect against mitm attacks, a single layer of protection and exposure that you are running multiple ssh targets behind your box. Your security is also limited to the strength of your password - although that looks OK on the surface, there are plenty of vulnerable long passwords  and if your password is compromised through any means its game over.

If you migrate from using a password to a key based setup and use a password/passphrase to secure your private key you will have a more secure setup.

If you want to further bolster security, the "gold standard" would be to run a VPN on your router, and for you to log in over VPN (again with a public/private or shared key system) before logging in on ssh across the VPN.  This would eliminate the port forwarding and advertising that ssh is running to the wider world, while providing an extra layer of protection.

Adding in a firewall only allowing connections from rfc1918 (private addresses - so across the vpn) will provide another layer of security and further curtail the risk of mitm attacks.

I would comment that using port 12345 over port 22 provides only minimal protection - anyone port scanning your IP would be able to find you have multiple instances of openssh exposed.

Answer (score 0):

In a setup like yours, this is usually as much secure as the connecting machine is.

This is where your credentials are entered and stored and this is where they can be stolen from.

Other than that, OpenSSH remote-exploitable vulnerabilities are rare and quickly patched. Be sure not to use outdated versions on both sides.

Depending on the stakes, you may want to improve the following:

1. Use public key or 2-factor (public key + password) authentication.
2. Use public key stored in a hardware token (especially good because most Windows machines can be safely considered to be "pwned".
3. Use a dedicated (not Windows) machine for logging in.
4. Setup some feedback (e.g. an email whenever someone logs in your Pi)
5. Subscribe to the mailing list that distributes openssh security advisories and act quickly when one is issued.
6. Setup a VPN to your router. Be aware that a misconfigured VPN can be an attack vector itself.

- Use your router (if ssh is available on it) as a jump host and use ssh port redirection instead of a destination NAT.

7. Use port-knocking techniques. Helps to keep logs clean, but can backfire by not being able to login because of unexpected port filtering in your internet connection.

Be warned that whatever you do, your ssh ports will be eventually found by the numerous bots that harvest the Internet and will be constantly banged with login attempts. If your Pi's log all of them, you will get lengthy logs full of these attempts that may fill the available space.